# Should this old question be deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Someone flagged [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14758/254) as "rude or abusive".

It wasn't closed (but it was heavily downvoted) at the time. Should it be closed and/or deleted now?

If I am reluctant to delete it, it's mostly because it has an upvoted answer (i.e. people might think the answer is useful and should stay).

Another alternative would be to put a "historical lock" on the question, which would add this text:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

A "historical lock" also [makes it more difficult to find the question using searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/139866).

So:

- Leave it as-is?
- Edit the question, to make the question milder (e.g. to remove most of the criticism), but keep the answers on-topic?
- Leave as-is but add a historical lock?
- Close and delete the question and all its answers?

Comment: I've never seen the "historical lock" before, but here in your question it sounds a much appropriate measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleared the flag before reading your post. I apologize for that.

I chose that the post should remain on our site as it has multiple answers and one with 9 upvotes.

Also if we chose to close/delete the post it would just verify OP's ideas about hostility.

I think its better to show him how Buddhism is and what values are being taught and practiced.

Answer (score 0):

I do not mind it being locked but ...

I option is it can be left as it is. This way new answers can accumulate. Also this leaves the possibility to edit the question to improve it to be more acceptable. Other who might find it offensive as it is can also downvote.

I guess generally locking is when content gets updated too often and floods the review queue. With the limited user base we ming not get updates too of then.

I do not think it should be deleted though. Deletion should be for spam like say someone advertises a flashlight by posting.

Editing may be a better way to resolve it also.